# React native, how to import react-native-sqlite-storage library

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I follow the below instruction for using sqlLite with prepared DB file

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#setting-up-your-project-to-import-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-from-application-for-ios

I could setup in Xcode without any problem, but I can not import correctly the library in the JS file.

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
console.log(SQLite) // {}
```

the SQLLite is an empty object. So, there is no the openDatabase method.

The library version is,

```
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you request permission??

Comment: what permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new version of docs, it's not updated but you can use like the below mention.

```
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

const createTable = ({ dbName, tableName, query }) => {
  const db = openDatabase({ name: dbName });

  db.transaction((txn) => {
    txn.executeSql(
      `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='${tableName}'`,
      [],
      (tx, result) => {
        if (result?.rows?.length === 0) {
          txn.executeSql(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${tableName}`, []);
          txn.executeSql(
            query,
            []
          );
          console.log(`DataBase ${dbName} with table name ${tableName} is created successfully`);
        } else {
          console.log(`DataBase ${dbName} with table name ${tableName} is already exists`);
        }
      },
      ({ message }) => console.log('Error caught while creating table', message)
    );
  });
};
```

Then use the below function to insert the data

```
const insertDataInTable = ({ dbName, tableName, query, values }) => {
  const db = openDatabase({ name: dbName });

  db.transaction((txn) => {
    txn.executeSql(
      query,
      values,
      (tx, result) => {
        console.log('result: ', result);
        for (let i = 0; i < result?.rows?.length; ++i) {
          console.log(`Data inserted into table '${tableName}' - `, result?.rows?.item(i));
        }
      },
      ({ message }) => console.log('Error caught while inserting data in table', message)
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native-sqlite-storage version 6.0.1 has following dependencies:

"devDependencies": {
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.63.2",
"react-native-windows": "^0.63.6"
}

It will not work with React18.